# Не удается отправить запрос из-за CORS

Tags: javascript, cors

Я пытаюсь сделать такой запрос:

```
  axios({
     method: 'get',
     url: 'https://site.test',
     headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     crossdomain: true,
     data: JSON.stringify(params)
  })
```

Но получаю ошибку: **CORS error**

Как это обойти? например из php скрипта через cURL запрос без проблем отправляется и приходит ответ. Но мне нужно именно на javascript все это сделать.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Никак не обойти. Обратиться к администратору сайта, чтобы он разрешил такой запрос

Comment: делай запрос через серверный прокси, это единственный вариант

Comment: Можешь запустить браузер в режиме no-cors

Comment: @Grundy что имеется в виду? Запрос отправлять на свой сервер, который будет curl'ом получать и передавать данные обратно?

Comment: @Leonid, принадлежность сервера не принципиальна. Можно проксироваться через любой другой подходящий сервер, не обязательно свой, например, можно использовать [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)

Comment: @Grundy воспользоваться сервисами cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, например? Насколько они навсегда?))

Comment: @Leonid, никто не гарантирует что и твой сервер будет "навсегда" Ж)

Comment: Это понятно, там просто и написано у них сразу: "Только в учебных целях". Вроде же несложно то же самое на своем организовать и не зависеть от других. Наверное и через nginx можно... Спасибо за наводку!